# What is the reason to disable csrf in spring boot web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

There are many tutorials where is shown how to disable csrf,

```
csrf().disable()
```

(and other possibilities like `.properties`, `.yml`, etc.)
but nowhere explained why they do this?

So my questions are:

What is the real-life reason to disable it?
Is it improves performance?

Comment: someone can use another token mechanism which is not csrf to authenticate requests, such as jwt, so there wont be any use of csrf token

Comment: In a tutorial, that might just be to make the tutorial simpler.

Comment: @benjaminc ok, i see, but why don't just forget about csrf().disable()? are jwt and standart csrf somehow interfere or disturb each other?

Comment: @Raedwald, i think just forget about  csrf().disable() is simplier )))

Comment: @arminvanbuuren it would make requests more verbose

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> What is the real-life reason to disable it?

The Spring documentation suggests:

> Our recommendation is to use CSRF protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by normal users. **If you are only creating a service that is used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.**

---

> Does it improve performance?

It shouldn't impact the performance. A filter (or another component) will be removed from the request processing chain to make the feature unavailable.

> What is the reason to disable `csrf` in a Spring Boot application?

1. You are using another token mechanism.
2. You want to simplify interactions between a client and the server.

Answer (score 7):

[Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#when-to-use-csrf-protection) recommend using it when serving **browser clients**, if not it may be disabled:

> Our recommendation is to use CSRF protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by normal users. If you are only creating a service that is used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.

I will add that even if you serve browser clients, but it's used internally only you may want/able to remove it.

Comment: So the essence of my question is: ** why** I may want to do this? What is the reason I'm so eager to disable it? Why cannot I just forget about it?

Comment: You do not want to disable CSRF protection for internal sites. This will allow attackers to bypass firewalls since CSRF happens within your browser which is present behind any firewalls. I'd recommend reading through https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.x/reference/html5/#csrf

Answer (score 4):

CSRF protects against what is aptly titled a Cross Site Request Forgery. In this type of attack, a token such as a session ID, is stored in the browser's cookies. The default behavior is to send the cookies with a request to a site. Someone can exploit this default behavior to impersonate you and do malicious things.

Here's how it works:

(this example carped from the Spring Security Reference docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.x/reference/html5/#csrf)

Your bank has a website and on this website there's a mechanism to
transfer money. You login and transfer a little money. You forget to logout. Then you navigate to an evil website.

The evil website duplicates this form and sends a request to transfer
100 bucks from your account to theirs. They can't see the cookie but
the cookies are sent with the request. They don't have to see the key
in order to turn the key in the lock. Because you forgot to logout,
your Session ID is still active (typically they expire but sometimes
they don't want to burden their customers with logging in every time).

The bank can't tell who sent the request, and they certainly can't
block all malicious websites since there are probably more malicious
sites than legitimate ones out there.

So, the bank enables CSRF protection which requires a special token to be generated for the request. The token will be embedded in the request and won't be stored in a cookie. Without this token, the request will rejected.

The token is generated by the legitimate site and if you're not navigating from this site's official page, then the token won't be generated. The evil website can't generate this token so they cannot forge the transaction.

To answer your question, why would you want to disable this? Here are some common reasons:

1. You have a different token mechanism already, such as JWT. JWT is typically used because the tokens can be passed to a JavaScript front end framework (such as Angular) which allows your front end to use the endpoints securely.
2. The endpoint does not actually "change the state of the application". This means it doesn't do anything a malicious attacker could exploit.
3. You are maintaining boundary security in some other way, such as an appliance that manages an enterprise's security.

There may be other reasons, but I didn't like the answer "because the tutorial was just trying to simplify". Why would a tutorial simplify? Well probably because of reason number 2: there's nothing of value to protect. But also a tutorial might actually be showing you how to implement JWT or some other token system.

Comment: `You have a different token mechanism already, such as JWT. JWT is typically used because the tokens can be passed to a JavaScript front end framework (such as Angular) which allows your front end to use the endpoints securely.` Handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended, so if you have this, you have some other serious vulnerabilities in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to disable if you have a different authentication mechanism that cannot be cloaked. For internal enterprise applications, not much of a concern.
We had to disable it because it was interfering with our existing authentication mechanism.