# Spring Security receiving 401 on Post Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hi I am learning Spring but when i felt starting convenient working with it, of course I came to a problem again... But this time I couldn't find any explanation even after hours of searching.

**Problem**
When doing a Post request I get a 401. If I do the get request everything works fine.
I created multiple Post request with and without Requestbody but allways the same problem. Also if I disable the authentication by using : `.requestMatchers("/api").permitAll()` I still get a 401 for the POST Request.

First I thougth about cors but first of all I am using postman and second of all Post without json shouldn't be a problem. usually.

**Reproduce Problem**

I created the following minimal project to reproduce the problem:

**Spring Security Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

}
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public String helloGet() {
        return "Hello from Get";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String helloPost() {
        return "Hello from Post";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```java
http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()); // or .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
```

into your `securityFilterChain` method.

If that works, it confirms that the "problem" was CSRF. Then I suggest read more on CSRF to check that it's safe disable it for your use case:

- [Understanding CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581488/understanding-csrf)
- [What is the reason to disable csrf in spring boot web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52363487/what-is-the-reason-to-disable-csrf-in-spring-boot-web-application)
- [Reason to disable CSRF in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696806/reason-to-disable-csrf-in-spring-boot)

Or investigate more on how to make your POST requests work *with* CSRF:

- [How do I send spring csrf token from Postman rest client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182701/how-do-i-send-spring-csrf-token-from-postman-rest-client)